# validar que un correo donde este este bien escrito

Tags: javascript, html

hice una validacion de correo pero esta valida todo lo que va despues del @ pero si le quito el @ este ya no valida, no hay alguna forma para evitar que verifique si com esta bien o hotmail,etc. anexo mi codigo.
este es la parte del imput

```html
    <form >
        <label for="correo">correo electronico</label>
        <input type="text" id="correo">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="validar Correo" onclick="validarCorreo(form.correo.value)">

    </form>


   <script>
        function validarCorreo(correo){
            var expReg= /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
            var esValido= expReg.test(correo);
            if(esValido==true){
                alert('El correo electronico  es valido');
            }else{
                alert('El correo no es valido');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Si uno ejecuta tu código (puedes verlo aquí mismo), probar con `pepito` dice no valido, con `pepito@pepito` dice no válido, `pepito@pepito.com` es valido. Cuál es el escenario que deseas modificar? Tu pregunta no es muy clara al respecto

Comment: Regex aplicado para emails es un tema debatible desde hace años que depende de qué según tú es válido y no, es un rabbithole. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: me gustaria que cuando escriba un correo verifique que este correcto si me falta una letra me mande el mensaje de no valido . un ejemplo si escribo hotmail.cm me mande el mensaje de no valido.

Comment: ¿Y como de seguro estas que no existe el dominio hotmail.cm? ¿O cualquier otro?

Comment: no sabia que existia esos dominios, perdona

Comment: ¿Y cómo tu regex adivinará qué dominio existe y que no?... recuerda que existen varios dominios aparte del `com`... por la cual no encuentro el sentido del objetivo de tu pregunta (a menos que seas más específico con lo que quieres lograr)...

Comment: De hecho, .cm es un dominio válido asignado actualmente a [camerún](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cm). Vas a tener que ser más específico con el significado de *"válido"* en tu contexto :)

Comment: yo pense que eran pocos los dominios existentes como .com, .mx, etc. pero una ves que veo su retro alimentacion me doy cuenta que no tiene logica mi pregunta. gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Una cosa es que el texto tenga "formato de email "y otra que ese email como tal exista y no rebote cuando se intenta enviar un email, son diferentes cosas.

Comment: y porque no usas `<input type="email" ` ??

Comment: yussef de alguna forma no me aparecia el mensaje no se si afecta bootstrap para que aparesca el mensaje